# Java.io in Processing.org

Tags: processing

Simple question I am trying to import Java.io.* to use

1. BufferedInputStream
2. FileOutputStream
3. BufferOutputStream

However even when I import them I get the following error:

```
"The package “java.io.BufferOutputStream” does not exist. You might be missing a library."
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its cool guys it was a classic FAIL... java typo.

it should be:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream
```